# How to upload dataset consisting of video files and use it in colaboratory?

Tags: video, machine-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I'm considering using colaboratory for a computer vision project. I need to download these video files from the internet (not locally) to colaboratory and use them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shell commands like `wget` or `curl` to download files via HTTP.

For example, executing the following snippet in a code cell will save the corresponding video to the local filesystem.

```
!wget http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4
```